# path helper generating exeception on console while migrating from Rails-2 to Rails-3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I am trying to modify my script, i am migrating from rails 2.3 to rails 3.1 but i am facing a strange issue. I see that when i use a path helper like this

in rails 3.1 i am getting an exception but rails 2.3 it used to work, by work i mean when to the path helper i pass values and order.customer_id is nil, it generates a path to create new customer however in rails 3.1 i see it generates a exception, below is the description of the error i see in rails 3.1

**`helper.link_to customer_email, app.store_customer_path(store,order.customer_id)`** , when order.customer_id is blank i get a exception on console as below

Below is the error i observe in rails 2.3

ActionController::RoutingError: store_customer_url failed to generate from **`{:controller=>"customers", :action=>"show", :store_id=#<object>}`**

. but when i load a web page i see that i get a path generated to create a new customer.

here is my relevant routes.rb code

```
        resources :stores do
      resources :customers do
        collection do 
          get :get_customers, :download, :csv_template
        end
        match :upload, :import, :map, :on => :collection
        member do
          get :more
        end
        resources :dropship_profiles
        resources :address
      end
end
```

But in rails 3.1

on console to i see exception and when loaded from browser also i see exception

I am not able to understand this and its confusing me, can anyone please help, Thanks.

Comment: have you tried passing valid values to your helper in console..does it work?

Comment: yes, with valid values it works, but with invalid values it throws exception, but on web page it works, i mean it shows a path to create new record

Comment: what do you mean by on webpage...irrespective of where the code is executed...if it has valid values,it works else it breaks.

Comment: webpage means when i load the page in browser, if customer id is nil it shows me path to create new customer, but in console it does not, it breaks and throws exception

Comment: store_customer_path should be valid irrespective of what values you are passing along with it...so as far as store_customer_path is valid,it should work.Can you share you routes.rb code. ?

Comment: ok let me edit the question with routes code

Comment: hi milind, i have edited my question with routes code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83118/discussion-between-milind-and-opensource-ios).

Answer (score 0):

After going through your `routes.rb`,i **dont see** any relevant path that routes to `store_customer_path`...kindly use the one present or create new one...verify by running `rake routes > path.txt` and then check your routes easily in `path.txt`

**=============UPDATED ANSWER==============**

### here you are passing two values,you just need to pass one

Instead of `helper.link_to customer_email, app.store_customer_path(store,order.customer_id)`
**try**

```
helper.link_to customer_email, app.store_customer_path(order.customer_id)
```

**or**

```
helper.link_to customer_email, app.store_customer_path(store.id)
```

As your path says `/stores/:store_id/customers/new(.:format)`,you just need to pass store_id for it to work.

for understanding **major changes in Routes from Rails 2 to Rails 3**...you must have a look at this [page](https://gregmoreno.wordpress.com/2010/08/12/rails-3-upgrade-part-2-routes/)

Comment: hi milind, i have verified that the path exists

Comment: this is what i see when i tried to see the named path on console. /stores/:store_id/customers/new(.:format)

Comment: hi milind, the problem i am facing is i am not able to understand why the same things works when loaded on browser in rails 2.3 and not in rails 3.1

Comment: well...there are many things which work in rails2 ,doesnt works in rails3 as many changes have been introduced which even includes Routing ...so you have to use compatible code and not the one used in rails2 .....